LINQPad 8 .NET 8 .NET 7 Conflict
I created a default LINQ-to-SQL context against my local db, and when I tried to create a new query on one of the databases I received:

CS1705 Assembly 'TypedDataContext_hfitox' with identity 'TypedDataContext_hfitox, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I'm not sure where the 7.0 reference is coming from (for the .NET dropdown in LINQPad, I've tried 'auto' as well), but wondering if there is a way to force built in contexts to use a different runtime?  I will have an issue in my 'real' query where I am referencing .NET 7 assemblies and using them, but you can see in image below that is not the case.  Any workarounds?


Have you tried refreshing the connection (right-click, Refresh)? Also, your query should default to .NET 8 if you have it installed unless you've configured LINQPad otherwise in Edit | Preferences. If not, try re-installing .NET 8 SDK.

So, when I drop down .NET, Auto is somehow configured to 7.0.20, but I do have 8.0.6 installed.  However, I DO want to use .NET 7, so reinstalling .NET 8 wouldn't help that situation would it?  The script I want to write will eventually reference libraries written against .NET 7.  (FYI, selecting .NET 8 made it work, I didn't try that thinking that Auto was .NET 8)

Do you have any references in your 'My Extensions' query or any extra dlls in the LINQPad Plugins folder? Failing that I would create a empty query without the connection (so it should compile) and look in ILspy to see if you can spot anything is being referenced.

LINQPad compiles data contexts against the reference assemblies of the lowest .NET version installed, so this is not expected behavior. I would try reinstalling both the .NET 7 and .NET 8 SDKs, in case something has gotten messed up, and then refresh your connection.
